# QMainWindow goes background after using QFileDialog

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qfiledialog

I have a Qt application that loads some file after clicking on button. I am using QFileDialog to open files. Every time I close file dialog, the application main window (QMainWindow) is behind all other opened windows (internet browser, explorer etc.). Is this standard behaviour? And is there any way to prevent this? I tried

```
    // set always on top window
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = this->windowFlags();
    this->setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

but it causes that also file dialog is behind main window.

Edited:
Here is fragment of code to call file dialog (method that calls it is static method of my class LoadData):

```
void MainWindow::on_buttonIP_clicked()
{
     loaded = LoadData::OpenFiles(IPFiles);
}

bool LoadData::openFiles(QStringList &fileNames)
{
    // open files dialog
    fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(0,
          tr("Open files"), "", "Text Files (*.txt *.dat *.points)");

    if (fileNames.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint is a wrong solution since it will lead to many problems. Could you please show how you are calling QFileDialog (the code)?

Comment: play with windows modality. It will help you to avoid the Main Window disappearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument of `QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames` must not be `nullptr`. Set it to your main window, and everything will be OK.